# What does the ":class" attribute do in HTML?

Tags: html, css, alpine.js

Why is there a second class attribute with a colon?

```
<div class="left-side" :class="{'active' : leftSide}">    
   <div class="logo">ULTRANET</div>
</div>
```

I would like to know if its supported.

Comment: Is this vanilla HTML?

Comment: It's supported by whatever evaluates that selector you got your example from. Some CMS, framework, library or something? It's not standard html...

Comment: I got it from https://codepen.io/TurkAysenur/pen/RwWKYMO

Comment: Ok, so in this case it's [AlpineJS](https://alpinejs.dev/) that's providing the functionality for that syntax.

Comment: `class` =/= `:class`. Those are different attributes. Your question title is misleading.

Comment: Look at the included resources using the gear icon in the JavaScript panel in that Pen.